# MediaWiki 1.27 warning requiring SpecialUserLogin.php

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I've updated my mediawiki from 1.26.2 to 1.27, the installation process finished ok, but when I try to access I received this error:

> Warning:
>   require(/var/app/current/includes/specials/SpecialUserLogin.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/app/current/includes/AutoLoader.php on line 81 Fatal error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/app/current/includes/specials/SpecialUserLogin.php'
>   (include_path='/var/app/current/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/mail_mime:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/mail_mime-decode:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/net_socket:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/var/app/current/vendor/pear/mail:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /var/app/current/includes/AutoLoader.php on line 81

I have no idea why is this happening. If I check the files in my server they're there. I'm also having template issues if I choose vector I only get a messed up template, without styling.

I'm using PHP 5.6.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Well, is `/var/app/current/includes/specials/SpecialUserLogin.php` there?

Comment: Yes, is there, I've found that the AWS server is missing some PEAR dependencies, I installed them, but the problem continues, on my localhost works ok though.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the autoloader tried to open `/var/app/current/includes/specials/SpecialUserLogin.php` (when loading the login page) and failed. If the file exists, you probably have some kind of permission problem.

Comment: Nope. I've already tried that! Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just stumbled across this same exact error after upgrading to MW 1.27.

In my case, the SpecialUserlogin.php existed and all of the permissions were right BUT the word login was written in lowercase so the system thought this file didn't exist. So I just renamed the SpecialUserlogin.php to SpecialUserLogin.php and b00m, it worked!

As for your templating issues, check the common.css file. Copy paste everything out of there, so it's empty, if you don't use it. And check that you're calling your style files correctly in your template.

Comment: You mean the SpecialUserlogin.php -error? Did you try to rename the file with uppercase "L" (SpecialUserLogin.php not SpecialUserlogin.php) if it was written in lowercase?

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was using git to commit and then deploy to an AWS env. It was super weird that git didn't recognize the typo neither.